# dynamic tableHeaderView does not work properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, tableview

I have a tableHeaderView that should be with dynamic height according to its content.

I tried use the systemLayoutSizeFitting & sizeToFit method in order to set new height for the table view, Unfortunately It's seems to be work well but not as I want (one of the dynamic UI get cropped). I tried to set the content compression resistance priority of the UIs that i want to be dynamic to (1000) but its dose not work as well.. every time at least one UI cropped.

[image: view simulator output image]

[image: another simulator output image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var podView: PodView!
@IBOutlet weak var postCaption: UILabel!

var pod: Pod!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //set header view
    podView.setPod(image: pod.image, title: pod.title, description: pod.description, viewWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    podView.sizeToFit()
    postCaption.text = pod.description
    postCaption.sizeToFit()
    let height = tableView.tableHeaderView!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    tableView.tableHeaderView!.frame.size.height = height
}
```

**edit:** constraint:

[view constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu39d.png)

[label Constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOPeW.png)

Comment: `let height = tableView.tableHeaderView!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    tableView.tableHeaderView!.frame.size.height = height` this is wrong way!!

Comment: so how can I calculate new height according autolayout? @SPatel

Comment: No, Just you need to set proper constraints

Comment: `tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`

Comment: please add your data source and delegate code

Comment: Its an tableHeaderView. not tableViewCell @SPatel

Comment: whatever it is!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For having `TableHeaderView` with dynamic height. Add following code to your viewController. It will work like charm.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame

        //Comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Make sure your tableHeaderView is having proper `AutoLayout` Constraints to get proper height.

Comment: yes, I tried this code before but for some reason Its calculate my xib view height but not calculate my label height . so if I want this to work I must add to the height variable my label height after sizeToFit() (height += postCaption.frame.size.height) and I don't want to do like so

Comment: forgot to mention you UP @Mehul Thakkar

Comment: Check the constraints of your view, it must work. In my code, i have label as well many other components. But above code is working 100% fine for me, @Gal

Comment: yes u right, its something probably with the label constraints because this script always output the height without the new label height its seems this always  calculate the that I set on builder interface.. any idea how to solve this? @Mehul Thakkar

Comment: I can help.. but show your TableHeaderView's constraints. You need to work out on that

Comment: I added the image of constraint down below the question @Mehul Thakkar

Comment: @Gal : Can you check that... have you given top and bottom constraints to all components in your tableheaderview or not.

Comment: yes! I have given top and bottom constraints to all components @Mehul Thakkar

but view and label are the only without HEIGHT constraint

Comment: Sorry @Gal, I cant figure out the issue that you have. For my case, i were having same use case as you and it is working perfectly fine with above code.

Comment: the problem was the UIImage size... to change the imageView frame its not enough with this func. So happy that I solved it :) @Mehul Thakkar

Answer (score 0):

**Try this steps for creating dynamic tableview header cell** :-

1 - Add one `UItableViewCell` on tableview from storyboard

2 - Create `tableView header`  UI as per your requirement.

3 - Create class as `TableViewHeaderCell` something according to your requirement what you want to show in header cell.

4 - Then in a ViewController class implement `headerview delegate method`.

```
/**
    Tableview header method 
*/
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

}
```

5 - In this method you want to create `TableViewHeaderCell` object and return `cell content View` like this.

```
    /**
    Table Header view cell implement and return cell content view when you create cell object with you identifier and cell name after that you have to mention height for header cell
    */
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell Identifier") as! CellName
                return cell.contentView
   }
```

6 - Implement `Tableview header height method`

```
/**
Here you can specify the height for tableview header which is actually your `TableViewHeader Cell height`
*/
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       //For eg
        return 100
    }
```

From this steps you can acheive **dynamic Header view cell as well as footer view cell** also, but for **footer view cell implement Tableview footer view delegate methods**.

Thank You,

Comment: its not help me that much because I don't want custom header. however I need a dynamic header that always will change its height to current content @Abhishek Jadhav

Comment: This is the way you can do dynamic header @Gal or you can create programmatically header also